# Java socket client doesn't stop reading the data

Tags: java, sockets

Hello i'm trying to execute a socket client in Java, but the client still reading the data and don't proceed with the program execution. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1987);
            System.out.println("Got connection");
            DataInputStream handshake = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            String handshakePure = handshake.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Got the handshake");
            System.out.println(handshakePure);
            DataOutputStream saida = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            saida.writeUTF("Got it!");
            saida.flush();
            saida.close();
            String returnedData = handshake.readUTF();
            System.out.println(returnedData);
            handshake.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think if that matter, but the socket server is a PHP socket server.

Comment: `DataInputStream.readUTF` reads a very specific message format. Does your PHP server use the same format? Add the PHP code to the question and we can advice if it's easier to change the PHP server or the Java client.

Comment: Yes both use the same format.

Comment: I very much doubt that. Post your code.

Comment: Man I already tested it with other clients and the same format, with python and php. But only the Java client is the only one with that problem.

Comment: `DataInputStream.readUTF` expects a uniquely weird message format, which is documented in the API specification. It is not a general purpose string read method. But I cannot suggest an alternative without knowing what the server is actually sending.

Comment: Maybe could it be a problem with the \n character in the string sent by the server? I saw the message which the server send and it have the \n.

Comment: The other thing is: when a trade the readUTF() to readLine() method it works normally! I don't know why a deprecated method works and the other not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataInputStream.readUTF` expects a uniquely weird message format. The first two bytes it reads are interpreted as the length of the string to read, in a big endian binary format. This is then followed by a weird non-standard text encoding similar to but incompatible with UTF-8. Most likely you should *not* be using `DataInputStream.readUTF` to read data in a program, unless you used its counterpart `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` to write it in the first place.

Based on your comments it sounds like your communication protocol is based on lines of text. To read lines of text, you can use for example the `BufferedReader` class.

```
BufferedReader handshake = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String handshakePure = handshake.readLine();
```